# proper way to show badge on internal GitLab Server

Tags: gitlab, badge, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

We have a company GitLab server that can't be accessed outside of the company network.

Is there any to show badges in that instance like `shield.io` does?

Answer (score 0):

The badges from shields.io or similar services are just URLs like `https://img.shields.io/npm/dt/vue`, for `img` tags and if they're in your README.md your users' browsers render them, not the Gitlab server. As far as it cares it's just text, so you can copy the URLs from shields.io, poser.pugx.org, or any other service you want to use and put them in `<img src="shields.io_url">` tags wherever you want them.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but If I want to use the dynamic query feature of shields.io, is that still true? shouldn't my endpoint be a public one?